# What is the correct way to specify multiple generic arguments in sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, sqoop

Checking at the documentation, I read that the list of the available generic arguments are:

```
Generic options supported are
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <local|namenode:port>      specify a namenode
-jt <local|jobtracker:port>    specify a job tracker
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.
```

I wanted to specify the following two properties in a sqoop command:

```
mapred.job.queuename=batch 
mapred.child.java.opts="\-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"
```

So I wrote my import sqoop script like this:

```
sqoop import -Dmapred.job.queuename=batch \
        mapred.child.java.opts="\-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom" \
        --connect $connection \
        --username $username\
        --password $password \
        --table $sourceTable \
        --columns "$columns"\
        --hive-import \
        --hive-overwrite \
        --hive-table $targetTable \
        --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
        --hive-delims-replacement "SPECIAL" \
        --null-string '\\N' \
        --null-non-string '\\N' \
        -m 1
```

But it's not working...

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/accumulo/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18/03/07 08:00:04 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.6.4.0-91
18/03/07 08:00:04 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import:
18/03/07 08:00:04 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: mapred.child.java.opts=\-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom
18/03/07 08:00:04 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --connect
```

I also thought about doing the following

```
sqoop import \
        -D mapred.job.queuename=batch \
        -D mapred.child.java.opts="\-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom" \
        --connect $connection \
        --username $username \
        --password $password \
        --table $sourceTable \
        --columns "$columns"\
        --hive-import \
        --hive-overwrite \
        --hive-table $targetTable \
        --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
        --hive-delims-replacement "SPECIAL" \
        --null-string '\\N' \
        --null-non-string '\\N' \
        -m 1
```

but I'm afraid only one of the two -D generic arguments will get parsed.

Which would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: You don't need a space after `-D`, and both should be parsed

Answer (score 0):

Java D flags don't need spaces after the properties

```
sqoop import \
    -Dmapred.child.java.opts="-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom" \
    -Dmapred.job.queue.name=batch \
```

Also fixed your queue name property